# How to get returned value and dump in rail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, marshalling, yield, dump

I am using database to cache somedata ( in this case I don't want to use memcache,memorycache...) in rails.
I want to cache everythings (value or returned value of block in rails) , so I have some code like below

```
def fetch
  if block_given?
    result = yield
    dump = Marshal.dump(result)
    ## some code to store dump in database
  end
end
```

and when i call

```
page = fetch("key") do
    MyModelInstance.where("query")
end
```

But I always receive a dumped of code block(**"MyModelInstance.where("query"**) ) when I store **dump** variable in database, not returned value of code block . I want active record model, not code block.

So is there any way to do excute code block then return value before dump in this case ? Thank

Comment: Add more examples. How are you calling this method, what is the resulting dump and what are you expecting instead. I tested it out and works fine for me.

Comment: @SiimLiiser I updated my post with example

Comment: ok, I see your problem now. give me a minute to come up with an aswer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your `fetch` method, it's how you call it. `yield` always returns the return value of the block, not the block itself. However, active record query methods (`all`, `where`, `order` etc.) do not return an array of models. If they did, it would be impossible to chain them.

```
MyModel.where("query").order(:created_at)
                      # Would be "Undefined method order for array"
                      # if where returned an array of models
```

`where` and all the other query methods return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. It behaves like an array, but it's not. This is the thing that is returned from your yield block and is being serialized.

If you want to serialize an array of models instead, call `to_a` on it to turn it to an array of models.

```
page = fetch("key") do
  MyModelInstance.where("query").to_a
end
```

Comment: So is there anyway I can excute codeblock and get returned value, when I use memcache or memorycache and use them like my fetch function, cache store can store returned value of code block not query chain, and if I use some trick in my fetch function ( print result ). I will get return value of code block

Comment: The relation IS the return value of the code block. I don't understand what you mean. If you want to always turn relations to arrays before storing, you can add specific code to handle that in the fetch function (if return value is a relation, call `.to_a` on it), but currently the code is doing exactly what you're claiming you want.